# 1292 Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: ''

Tags: mysql, moodle, insert-update

I am running this query on mysql server but I received warning.
        update mdl_context
    set depth=2,
    path= concat('/1/',id)
    where contextlevel=50
    and exists (select "x" from mdl_course c where c.id= mdl_context.instanceid  and c.category=0)
       and (mdl_context.path is null or mdl_context.depth =0);

errors=>
0 row(s) affected, 64 warning(s): 1292 Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: ''

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MySQL 'Truncated incorrect INTEGER value'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4946899/mysql-truncated-incorrect-integer-value)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try replacing

```
SELECT "x"
```

with

```
SELECT c.id
```