# using string values for between operator in mysql

Tags: mysql, casting, between

I have a table `sales` having attributes as `salesId,salesDate,..etc`. The `salesId` column is a `varchar`.I need to concat the `year` value of the `salesDate` to the `salesId` based on a condition of the `month` of the `salesDate`. I need to do this for a range of around 100 salesID.
Eg: old `salesId` = 7  and corresponding salesDate = '2018-05-07' then new required
 `salesId = '7/2018-2019'`
So i tried the following :

```
    update sales
set salesId = case
                when month(salesDate)>=4 then concat(salesId,concat("/",year(salesDate),"-",year(salesDate)+1))
                else
                    concat(salesId,concat("/",year(salesDate)-1,"-",year(salesDate)))
                end
where cast(salesId as unsigned) between "7" and "10";
```

However, i get the following error:

```
Error Code: 1292. Truncated incorrect INTEGER value: '1/17-18'
```

I even tried without using any `Cast()` as

```
    update sales
set salesId = case
                when month(salesDate)>=4 then concat(salesId,concat("/",year(salesDate),"-",year(salesDate)+1))
                else
                    concat(salesId,concat("/",year(salesDate)-1,"-",year(salesDate)))
                end
where salesId between "7" and "10";
```

but in this case the query runs fine but i get:

```
0 row(s) affected Rows matched: 0  Changed: 0  Warnings: 0
```

I can't figure out the error or how to proceed.Could someone please provide some guidance in this ?
Thanks.
Sample data

```
salesId salesDate
7          2017-05-15
8          2017-06-16
9          2017-07-18
10         2017-08-20
```

...

```
Required Result

 salesId                  salesDate
    7/2017-2018         2017-05-15
    8/2017-2018         2017-06-16
    9/2017-2018         2017-07-18
    10/2016-2017        2017-02-20
```

Comment: Please provide sample data and expected results. It is not that clear what you are trying to accomplish here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error which i was getting earlier was actually a warning as stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4946899/mysql-truncated-incorrect-integer-value). So after using update ignore i was able to execute the query as get expected results.
However i would be waiting for a more comprehensive answer as to get it working without the need to ignore.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The field salesId must  be text like

You have to change your Update query to include if thecolumn where already update, so that it takes with SUBSTRING_INDEX only the number

```
 update sales
set salesId = case
                when month(salesDate)>=4 then concat(SUBSTRING_INDEX(salesId,'/',1),concat("/",year(salesDate),"-",year(salesDate)+1))
                else
                    concat(SUBSTRING_INDEX(salesId,'/',1),concat("/",year(salesDate)-1,"-",year(salesDate)))
                end
where cast(SUBSTRING_INDEX(salesId,'/',1) as unsigned) between "7" and "10";
```

so that your update function can work

> ```
> CREATE TABLE sales (
>   `salesId` VARCHAR(20),
>   `salesDate` VARCHAR(10)
> );
>
> INSERT INTO sales
>   (`salesId`, `salesDate`)
> VALUES
>   ('7', '2017-05-15'),
>   ('8', '2017-06-16'),
>   ('9', '2017-07-18'),
>   ('10', '2017-08-20');
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
>
> ✓
> ```

> ```
>     update sales
> set salesId = case
>                 when month(salesDate)>=4 then concat(salesId,concat("/",year(salesDate),"-",year(salesDate)+1))
>                 else
>                     concat(salesId,concat("/",year(salesDate)-1,"-",year(salesDate)))
>                 end
> where cast(salesId as unsigned) between "7" and "10";
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> SELECT *  from sales
> ```
>
> ```
> salesId      | salesDate 
> :----------- | :---------
> 7/2017-2018  | 2017-05-15
> 8/2017-2018  | 2017-06-16
> 9/2017-2018  | 2017-07-18
> 10/2017-2018 | 2017-08-20
> ```

> ```
>  update sales
> set salesId = case
>                 when month(salesDate)>=4 then concat(SUBSTRING_INDEX(salesId,'/',1),concat("/",year(salesDate),"-",year(salesDate)+1))
>                 else
>                     concat(SUBSTRING_INDEX(salesId,'/',1),concat("/",year(salesDate)-1,"-",year(salesDate)))
>                 end
> where cast(SUBSTRING_INDEX(salesId,'/',1) as unsigned) between "7" and "10";
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> SELECT *  from sales
> ```
>
> ```
> salesId      | salesDate 
> :----------- | :---------
> 7/2017-2018  | 2017-05-15
> 8/2017-2018  | 2017-06-16
> 9/2017-2018  | 2017-07-18
> 10/2017-2018 | 2017-08-20
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=47ac08c1287819d6b8fcff4465417fd0)*

Comment: yes the field salesId is already a varchar. I tired your above snippet but i still get the error: `Error Code: 1292. Truncated incorrect INTEGER value: '1/17-18'
`

Comment: please show me your create table or make a fiddle to demonstrate your problem, as far as i can read your error message it shows your salesId is integer not Varchar in the right size

Comment: the salesID is varchar(100) however the salesDate is of type date

Comment: however this also gives correct results https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=acab94a38ba7470c4eaea92aba7cf1ea   but not in my db

Comment: your error code shows 1/17-18 which would not be affected in your update query, try it with your actual table on sql fiddle and see if you can reproduce it, you could also see if your mysql version can be updated, sometimes it is simpky buggy

Comment: mysql version is 8.0.13..Moreover, the update query is working fine if i update for individual records, i.e without using the between operator.

Comment: i.e 
`update sales
set salesId = case
    when month(salesDate)>=4 then concat(salesId,concat("/",year(salesDate),"-",year(salesDate)+1))
                else
     concat(salesId,concat("/",year(salesDate)-1,"-",year(salesDate)))
    end
where salesId ="10";  `

Comment: Ok i get it i changed my answer, so that your error doesn't occur, Please add next time your complete data, because your data doesn't show, that the ids arent ids at all, at least not  that simople